# Добавление информации в поля нового столбца в таблице базы данных

Tags: mysql

В базе данных `mysql` я создал таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id int AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
first_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(30),
email varchar(50)
);
```

Затем решил обновить таблицу добавив в нее новый столбец:

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD telephone varchar(15);
```

До того как был добавлен новый столбец `telephone`, были добавлены несколько пользователей.
Вопрос такой, какой командой добавляется информация в пустые строки столбца `telephone`, для уже имеющихся пользователей?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно обновить данные, команда `Update`

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

Например

```
UPDATE users
SET telephone = '000000'
WHERE user_id = '0';
```

Обновляет запись юзера с `id = 0`, задаёт колонке `telephone` номер `000000`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Только встал еще один вопрос, incorrect string value mysql '\x8A\xE0\xA8\xE1\xE2\xAE...' это я так понял он жалуется на unicode? И как ее исправить?

Comment: у вас phpmyadmin?

Comment: *как ее исправить?* Ну по-хорошему - правильно настроить клиента, чтобы он отдавал данные в правильной кодировке. Или в тексте запроса явно использовать функцию CONVERT(). Впрочем. функция не поможет, если отправляемые серверу от клиента данные по чарсету не соответствуют настройке соединения.

Comment: Благодарю. Попробую все способы)